# Why does F# have a unary plus operator?

Tags: f#, unary-operator

Some languages use a unary plus operator for implicit conversions, such as coercing a string to a number (e.g. Javascript) or casting small number types to an `int` (e.g. most C-based languages), or to be used when overloading operators.

Since the unary plus is primarily used for hackish purposes like this, and also since F# does not perform automatic widening conversions, I was surprised that F# includes the unary plus.

What adds to my surprise is that Haskell does not have a unary plus operator. Since the F# design was influenced by Haskell, I'm curious as to why it was decided that F# needed a unary plus when Haskell apparently didn't.

Can you give an example of a credible use for the unary plus in F#? If you can't, why is it included in the language at all?

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be for the same reason as in Ruby. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680587/whats-the-point-of-unary-plus-operator-in-ruby

Comment: Ocaml has an unary plus, named `(~+)`. I don't know what it is for either.

Comment: I think all languages have it, and none use it. It is there for symmetry.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I looked [here](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~dmatusze/resources/ocaml/ocaml.html#intops) and it listed a unary negation prefix operator, but not a unary plus operator. I'd like to see a reference that lists it. If you can find one, I'll correct my question.

Comment: Perhaps more interesting is overloading it doesn't seem to work: `let (~+) n = -n`. `+1` still returns `1`. I _must_ be doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 is not ((~+) 1), but actually the number 1 (it is resolved by the lexer). `+(1)` returns `-1`.

Comment: @PeterOlson: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html -> Integer arithmetic

Comment: F# is based on OCaml, and only *influenced* by Haskell. If OCaml has it, it is very reasonable that F# will have it.

Comment: @RamonSnir: Ah, thanks. Apparently, inserting a space works too: `+ 1` returns `-1`.

Comment: But...why on earth would you ever need to use it in either F# or OCaml?

Comment: As I said, mostly for symmetry (we do have the `(~-)` operator). I guess also for some special types you'd want it to be overloaded. I'm going to check FAKE, I think they've overloaded it.

Comment: @RamonSnir: Some languages _do_ use it, but I would consider them poor uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do/3903114#3903114

Comment: @Daniel That's awful, and won't work on F#.

Comment: This comment thread is getting pretty long. Why don't we [move it to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4697/why-doesnt-f-have-a-unary-plus-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll summarize the extended comments. Possible reasons (until a more authoritative answer is given):

1. Consistency with OCaml, from which F# is derived *(if you're doing something wrong/unnecessary it's best to keep doing it so people know what to expect :-))*
2. Overloading (mostly for custom types)
3. Symmetry with unary negation

Comment: By the same token, we should add a unary "yes" operator to the language to make it symmetric with the unary "not" (`!`) operator. We could further justify the inclusion of the "yes" operator because it would be useful when somebody wants to overload it for their own custom type.

Comment: `!` is dereference, not `not`. There is a positive counterpart for the `not` function, and it is called `id`.

Comment: @PeterOlson I would call it the "indeed" operator. "If indeed x equals three..."

Comment: I agree with you. Since the only significant use of it I've encountered has been in C, I wonder if it's merely an artifact in most languages.

Comment: @RamonSnir: Maybe being a bit pedantic here, but I wouldn't say `not` (`bool -> bool`) and `id` (`'a -> 'a`) are counterparts.

Comment: They are symmetric, because (for booleans) `not` returns the opposite (its negative value), while `id` returns the same. `(~+)` for numbers simply returns them, that is `id`.

Comment: I said I was being pedantic. :-) If there was a general concept of inversion, which could apply to any type, I would consider it `id`'s counterpart in the strictest sense. But for `bool`s, `id`/`not` does the trick.

Comment: One use case for your points 2 and 3 would be complex numbers, where `+i` looks like quite a natural counterpart to `-i`, even if it is really just the same as `i`.

Comment: @PeterOlson: If a type overloads `!` to return a Boolean, I think `!!` should behave as a "yes" operator, and a good compiler should interpret `if (!!x) y; else z;` as `if (!x) z; else y;`.

Answer (score 2):

F# has two core influences:

1. OCaml, with which it was originally compatible, and
2. the CLR, on which it is built.

As has been pointed out, OCaml has a unary plus operator, so from that point of view, it was natural for F# to have one as well.

As for the CLR... To my surprise, the Common Language Specification doesn't specify any requirements for languages to support operator overloading. However, it does specify semantics and naming conventions when the mechanism is used. Still, F# was allowed to opt out of using unary plus, just like C# and VB opted out of support for overloading compound assignment operators (`+=`, etc.).

The most common .NET languages aside from F# (C#, VB and C++/CLI) do allow it and have a unary plus. So from this point of view as well it would be natural for F# to have support for a unary plus operator.

Comment: "*just like C# and VB opted out of supporting compound assignment*" C# supports compound assignment operators. ;-]

Comment: Yes, but they don't follow the CLI spec. If you define a `+=` operator in C++/CLI, using `+=` in C# won't call it. In F# it will.

Answer (score 2):

There is a unary plus operator in standard mathematical notation. Most programming languages have standard math notation as the original influence and motivation for the syntax of arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) "Used to declare an overload for the unary plus operator."

Comment: That's what it says `~+` is for. It also says that for the `~-`, so this doesn't really answer my question.