# String concatenation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to understand string concatenation.

Why doesn't the fourth line give the same result as the second one?

```
counter = 0
"#{counter+1}. test" gives "1. test"
counter = 0
"#{++counter}. test" gives "0. test"
```

Comment: same result or different results, moreover ruby does not support the `++` operator

Comment: See this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680587/whats-the-point-of-unary-plus-operator-in-ruby

Comment: Just asked a question going into a little more detail on this that I'm curious about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085607/ruby-unary-operator-behavior  It also illustrates how you can redefine the unary `+` operator which might shed a little light on why it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++` just looks like the increment operator. It's actually two unary `+` operators, so it's just the same as plain old `counter`

Answer (score 2):

Because, `++` is not an operator for Ruby like C or Java.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `++` operator in Ruby. What `++counter` says is "give me the positive result of the positive result of 0" which is 0.

Answer (score 2):

`++` is not an operator in Ruby. If you want to use a pre-increment operator then use:

```
counter += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, `++x` or `--x` will do nothing! In fact, they behave as multiple *unary* prefix operators: `-x == ---x == -----x == ......`  or `+x == +++x == +++++x == ......`

To ***increment*** a number, simply write `x += 1`.

To ***decrement*** a number, simply write `x -= 1`.

Proof :

```
x = 1
+x == ++++++x # => true
-x == -----x # => true
x # => 1 # value of x doesn't change.
```

Answer (score 1):

**In C**

```
++counter //Pre Increment 
counter++// Post Incremet
```

**But In Ruby** ++ has no existence ,

**So if** you want to increment a variable then you have to simply write

```
counter = counter + 1
```

In your case you have to write just

```
 "#{counter = counter + 1}. test" gives "1. test"
```

And will increment the value **counter**  by **1**