# Unary operators behavior

Tags: ruby, operators, operator-overloading

Had some weird results when redefining the unary `+` operator in Ruby on the `Fixnum` class. Not exactly sure why things are happening the way they are (specifically line `009`).

```
irb:003> class Fixnum
irb:004>   def +@ #define unary +
irb:005>     15
irb:006>   end
irb:007> end
=> nil
irb:008> 2
=> 2
irb:009> +2
=> 2
irb:010> +(2)
=> 15
irb:011> ++2
=> 15
```

Comment: In `+(2)`, `2` is the argument of the method `+`; the same as `+ 2`.  There is no method `++`, so `++2` is interpreted as `+(+2)`, or `+(2)`.

Comment: So what you're getting at is that `+ 2` calls the `+@` method, while `+2` is just viewed as the literal `2` by the parser/interpreter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing a side effect of the parser's behavior in how it interprets numeric literals.

If we create our own class:

```
class C
  def +@
    11
  end
end
```

and then look at some things:

```
> c = C.new
> +c
 => 11 
> ++c
 => 11
```

That's exactly what we expect to happen. If we use your `Fixnum` unary `+` override and a `Fixnum` variable:

```
> n = 23
> +n
 => 15 
> ++n
 => 15
```

then again we see what you're expecting. In both cases, we see the result of calling the `+@` method on a non-literal.

But when we look at `+6` with your operator in place:

```
> +6
 => 6
```

the `+@` method is not called. Similarly if we override `-@`:

```
class Fixnum
  def -@
    'pancakes'
  end
end
```

and see what it does:

```
> -42
 => 42
```

So what's going on here? Well, Ruby is seeing `+6` and `-42` not as `6.send(:+@)` and `42.send(:-@)` method calls but as single literals for positive six and negative forty-two.

If you start adding parentheses, `+(6)` and `-(42)`, then Ruby sees non-literal expressions and ends up calling the unary methods. Similarly when you double the unary operators.

Comment: Added an answer of my own that you might be interested in seeing - it just shows that what you were saying is correct, but it's neat to see anyways

Answer (score 2):

*This answer adds additional details to mu's answer.*

Just learned about ruby's [`Ripper`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) class, and it shows what's happening pretty clearly:

```
require 'ripper'

p Ripper.sexp('2')     # => [:program, [[:@int, "2", [1, 0]]]]
p Ripper.sexp('+2')    # => [:program, [[:@int, "+2", [1, 0]]]]
p Ripper.sexp('+(2)')  # => [:program, [[:unary, :+@, [:paren, [[:@int, "2", [1, 2]]]]]]]
p Ripper.sexp('++2')   # => [:program, [[:unary, :+@, [:@int, "+2", [1, 1]]]]]
```

Comment: I just saw you playing around with this stuff over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23879544/479863).

Comment: Haha yup, that's what made me think of this question. `Ripper` seems like a great tool to answer this kind of thing with