# Undefined method '+@'

Tags: ruby

I can't understand why this is not working; all three elements should be strings.

```
i = 5
base = "somestring"
base = i.to_s +" #{base} " + i.to_s # => Undefined method '+@'
```

Why does it interpret it as a method? I thought maybe it has something to do with setting `base` equal to a part of itself, but this seems to work:

```
base = "#{base}"
```

Comment: You need a space between `+` and `"` in your third line

Comment: Wow, awesome thanks. That's such a small detail. I thought spacing didn't matter in Ruby?

Comment: Spacing matters quite a bit in Ruby. Consider the difference between `f(x, y)` and `f (x, y)` for another example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question! In ruby, the `+@` method defines the behavior of the unary + operator. In other words, it defines what happens when you have an expression like `+someSymbol`.

So, in this case, it's seeing the part of your expression, `+" #{base} "` and trying to apply the unary + method to the string, which doesn't exist.

Try adding a space between the `+` and the start of your string.

---

What's also interesting is that this only happens in some cases.

```
i = 2
i.to_s +"foo" # => NoMethodError: undefined method `+@` for "foo":String
"2" +"foo"    # => "2foo"
```

So what's going on? `i.to_s +"foo"` is equivalent to `i.to_s(+"foo")`. And now you can see why the unary + function is being called and not the string concatenation operator.

---

So, you have other options to fix your code:

```
i.to_s() +" #{base} " + i.to_s
```

or even

```
"#{i} #{base} #{i}"
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot. So I guess that spacing really does matter in Ruby then?

Comment: That's interesting.  At least `i.to_s +"foo"` raises an exception. No such luck with `"4".to_i +4 => 0` or `"4".to_i +6 => 4`, which could be a challenge to debug.  Your `or even` would have raised an eyebrown had I not seen that in another recent question.  Very odd.

Comment: Yep, you can get some pretty fun results  `i=6; i.to_s +5 #=> "11"` It added the numbers! Or did it... :)

Comment: Or just add space before and after `+` (`i.to_s + " #{base} " + i.to_s`)

Answer (score 3):

Add space around `+` operator. Otherwise it's treated as unary `+` operator:

```
i.to_s + "#{base} " + i.to_s
        ^
```